# Django How to submit and handle form data in class based views

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Can anybody tell me how to handle form submit and fields using class based views.
Here is my views.py

```
class ProfileView(FormView):
    template_name='profile.html'
    form_class = UnregisterMealForm
    context={}
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def form_valid(self, form):

        return HttpResponse("You have succesfully unregistered for the meal")
    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

    def dispatch(self,*args, **kwargs ):

        if self.request.user.is_active:

            context = super(ProfileView, self).dispatch( self.request, *args, **kwargs)

            return context                
        else:        
            return HttpResponseRedirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.LOGIN_URL, self.request.path))
    def get_context_data( self, **kwargs):
            form=UnregisterMealForm(self.request.POST)
            meals = ['breakfast','lunch','dinner']
            context = {'meals' : meals , 'unregisterform': form}

            if form.is_valid():
                select_date = request.POST['select_date']
                select_meal = request.POST['meal']
                context['recent'] = "You have succesfully unregistered    for "+ select_meal +" on " + select_date 

        return context
```

When I submit the form, it shows an error `Attribute Error 'UnregisterMealForm' object has no attribute 'user'`

Here is my `UnregisterMealForm`

```
class UnregisterMealForm(forms.Form):
    MEALS = [('breakfast','breakfast'),('lunch','lunch'), ('dinner','dinner')]
    select_date = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput())
    meal = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=MEALS, attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placehoder':'Choose the Meal' }))
```

Can anybody help me with this. If you need more information please tell me.

Thanks in advance. 
I m a novice in django.

Comment: post your models.py and UnregisterMealForm

Comment: It is not a modelform. I have added UnregisterMealForm. Can you help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: You shouldn't be dealing with the form inside `get_context_data`.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Okay. But, can i pass context data through form_valid method ? I think the Attribute Error is because the view is decorated with `login_required`. How to get rid of this and submit form data. ? Thanks

Comment: No. When the form is valid, you must always redirect to another view. And yes, the decorator needs to be around the `dispatch` method, or around the view name in the URL pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can save object in your form_valid method:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    model = YourModel()
    model.select_date = form.cleaned_data['select_date']
    model.select_meal = form.cleaned_data['meal']
    model.save()
    messages.success(request, "Your message here")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Why is it showing Attribute error ( I mentioned it above )??